# In IBM cloud how could I get access group list using curl command. But I am facing an error which is the base url?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to execute the curl command in IBM cli command

```
curl -X POST --location --header "Authorization: Bearer <SAMPLE IAM TOKEN>" 
--header "Accept: application/" 
--header "Content-Type: application/" --data '{ "name": "Managers", "description": "Group for managers" }'
 "<sample URL>/v2/=<ACCOUNT ID>"
```

Note: The actual command executed on the image due Stackoverflow formatting

Comment: What is the error? Are you referring to this API? https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-access-groups#list-access-groups

Comment: It gives me unauthorized message

Comment: can you give me a complete sample command?

Comment: First, add the command you executed AND the error message. Have you followed the instructions on how to obtain the bearer token?